# How to rename index.html after build in a Vite plugin?

Tags: vite

I want to run a completely orthodox Vite build and then after the build, change my index.html file into an index.php file. This is to integrate it with a Wordpress plugin.
I was able to uncomment the php code in my index.html file but have not been able to figure out how to rename the file after the build.

Researching this question only yields answers for how to change the entry file *during* the build or a solution that uses Webpack. Any help appreciated!

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  base: "/path-to-plugin",
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    {
      name: "wordpress-php-entry",
      enforce: 'post',

      // uncomment php code in index.html
      transformIndexHtml(html) {
        return html.replace(/<!--/g, '').replace(/-->/g, '');
      },

      // rename index.html to index.php
      

    }
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: It's not unfortunately. When the file has a php extension, Vite treats it differently and is unable to parse it.